# decompressing string from database in python

Tags: python, encoding, zlib, bytea

I know this question will looks a bit unclear but I reached a level of frustration that drives me to ask this here..

I'm working with data from a POSTGRESQL database, and I get something like this:

```
2022-06-01 02:21:52.770293  2022-06-01 02:21:52.78704   \\x0a78daa5534d6fe32014fc2fdca90063b0c9a91f52d...
2022-06-01 02:21:55.991809  2022-06-01 02:21:56.04597   \\x0a78dac5534d6be33010fd2fbe2b58b264c9caa9ed4...
```

I know that the counter column in a compressed string that contains JSON-like data.
I know (because it was already decompressed in the past) that the usage of `zlib` package can decompress this string (by something like `zlib.decompress(mycompressedstring)`

But there is a missing step here because this string `\\x0a78...` is not decompressable.
I suspect there is an encoding-decoding work to do before calling zlib but I struggle to find what to do..

I tried:

```
test = bytes(sample.iloc[1]['counter'], 'UTF16')
```

This leads to something like:
[image]

I was thinking it is better but zlib cannot decompress this

```
testunc = zlib.decompress(test)
```

```
error: Error -3 while decompressing data: incorrect header check
```

Please, can someone help me there? Bu giving me a track to follow to fing what is wrong with this...

Comment: Please [*do not* use images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/3439404) in your [mcve].
Copy the actual text, paste it into the question, then format it as code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The hexadecimal representations starting with `78da`... are the starts of valid zlib streams. You need to discard the `\\x0a` and convert the remainder from hexadecimal to binary. The result of that would be given to `zlib.decompress()`. Look at `a2b_hex` in [binascii](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/binascii.html#binascii.unhexlify).

Comment: many thanks! it saves my whole week

Comment: By curisosity, @mark how do you know that 78da is a valid start of zlib stream?

Comment: a) I instantly recognized it, having looked at many zlib streams, and b) I tested it and the subsequent bytes to see if, as far as they went, they were a valid zlib header followed by valid deflate compressed data. They are.